# Cognito SignIn throws "Page not found, http error 405" when login from 2 browser tabs

Tags: amazon-cognito

Issue: Facing Cognito SignIn issue ("Page not found, http error 405 error") with valid credentials in different tabs in same browser instance.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a browser tab(chrome latest version) and enter the login url as below for a configured client app, sample URL: https://xxx.cognito-domain/login?response_type=code&client_id=yyy&redirect_uri=zzzzz
2. Do not enter the credentials at this point.
3. Then open the tab2 (in the same browser instance) and enter the login url again for the same configured client app
   https://xxx.cognito-domain/login?response_type=code&client_id=yyy&redirect_uri=zzzzz
4. Enter the valid credentials in one tab and press Sing-In, Cognito redirects you to call back url. Which is expected.
5. Now, in another tab enter the same valid credentials and press SignIn.
6. Cognito throws "http 405 error code" with "This page isn’t working, If the problem continues, contact the site owner.HTTP ERROR 405"

It works in the below ways:
1. If i open a tab and enter the credentials, it is working as expected.
2. After that if i enter the same url in another tab, due to single SignOn the application takes me to the application page properly.

In Another tab also, if i enter the valid credentials it should take me to the application page rather than HTTP 405 Error.

Answer (score -1):

I was also on `spring-boot` has two tabs on the browser to login at the same time but `HTTP 405 error` has occurred on a tab